Create a radarchart with dynamic grouping which is based on shiny widget
This is a shiny app in which first I need to select 3 or more columns from the selectinput() named Variable and then 1 from the Group selectInput().The first works as with this I set which variables am I going to use in my radarchart. The second I want to be used in order every time to create a radarchart with a legend based on the values of the selected Group with different color for each group
# Load necessary libraries
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(fmsb)

# Sample data (replace this with your actual data)
Test_RShiny_Data <- structure(list(abs_edu = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), abs_employ = c(1, 
                                                                                                              1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), abs_wash = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                       0, 1, 1), abs_health = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), abs_protection = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), abs_document = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               1, 1, 1, 1), ast_hhasset = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1), ast_itc = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), ast_transport = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0, 0, 1, 0, 0), ast_nonessential = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          0, 0), ast_employ = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), ast_save = c(0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), sc_safecom = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0, 0, 1, 1), sc_group = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), sc_safeharass = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), sc_safeterror = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0, 1, 1, 1, 1), sc_safehh = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
                                                    ac_edu = c(3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3), ac_numemploy = c(0, 
                                                                                                               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0), ac_supportwork = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 
                                                                                                                                                              1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1), ac_tension = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                1, 1), cs = c(1, 1, 1, 0.441957086324692, 1, 0, 0.441957086324692, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.441957086324692, 1, 1), ge = c(0.526506841182709, -0.51858788728714, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.526506841182709, -0.51858788728714, -0.51858788728714, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               0.243249282240868, 0.243249282240868, -0.51858788728714, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               -0.51858788728714, 0.526506841182709), gbv = c(0.770168602466583, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.770168602466583, 0.770168602466583, 0.770168602466583, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.770168602466583, 0.770168602466583, -0.0019789848010987, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -0.0019789848010987, 0.770168602466583, 0.770168602466583
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               ), country = c("Ukrainian", "Ukrainian", "Moldovan", NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Ukrainian", "Ukrainian", "Ukrainian", "Ukrainian", "Ukrainian", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              "Ukrainian"), marital = c("Seperated/divorced/widowed", "Seperated/divorced/widowed", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Married", "Married", "Single/Engaged", "Married", "Seperated/divorced/widowed", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Seperated/divorced/widowed", "Seperated/divorced/widowed", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "Seperated/divorced/widowed"), child = c("1-3 children", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "1-3 children", "More than 3 children", "1-3 children", "1-3 children", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "1-3 children", "1-3 children", "1-3 children", "1-3 children", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 "1-3 children"), ageg = c(2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Define UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Dynamic Bar Plot"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("variable", "Select 3 or more variables", choices = colnames(Test_RShiny_Data),multiple = T),
      selectInput("Group", "Group by", choices = colnames(Test_RShiny_Data),multiple = F),
      
      actionButton("goButton", "Go")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("radarPlot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # Reactive expression to process the data
  processed_data <- reactive({
    req(input$goButton)  # Ensure the button is clicked
    isolate({
      myvars <- input$variable
      newdata <- Test_RShiny_Data[myvars]
    })
   
      
    
  })
  

  
  output$radarPlot <- renderPlot({
    
    
    
    radarchart(processed_data(), axistype = 1, 
               pfcol = colors_fill,
               
               title = "Correlations of the sub-variables with the AC Pillar", 
               pcol = 1:ncol(processed_data()), plwd = 2, plty = 1,
               cglty = 1, cglwd = 0.5, cglcol = "black", 
               vlcex = 0.8, caxislabels = seq(0, 1, by = 0.2),
               maxmin = TRUE)
legend(x=0.7, y=1, legend = colnames(processed_data()[input$Group,]), bty = "n", pch=20  , text.col = "grey", cex=1.2, pt.cex=3)

  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)


colors_fill is undefined.  If you comment out that part, it works fine.

it does not work as expected. when for example abs_edu is selected the 2 components of the legend should be 0 and 1 and so on

legend = colnames(processed_data()[input$Group,]) does not make sense.  Perhaps it should be legend = colnames(processed_data()[input$variable])

there is only one legend.the group is the correct choice. the variable is for other thing

https://r-graph-gallery.com/143-spider-chart-with-saveral-individuals.html here is from where I saw it but here they use rownames

Your data is not set-up the way it is required by fmsb package.  Please look at the example.  It should have a row for max and min, and all other rows are considered as data series to be plotted.
